# System.StackOverflowException when two scripts of a project create instances of each other

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow, method-call

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLFFw.jpg
^ MainMenu script needs to call the LogIn script to show LogIn form.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIfpM.jpg
^ LogIn script needs to call MainMenu script to:

mainmenu.lblTitle.Text = username;

I've created an instance of LogIn so I can open LogIn's form in a new window when I click a button. Then once I've entered the username and password and click a button, the LogIn script needs to call the MainMenu script to change the text on one of its form's labels.

I'm a beginner at C#

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as *text* rather than as screenshots. Fundamentally though, this is nothing to do with WinForms - you'd see the same issue in a simple console app. Having two classes each create a new instance of the other, unconditionally, in construction, is always going to fail. Even if each of them needs a reference to an instance of the other doesn't mean that they should *create* instances of each other. But a better design is almost certainly to make the LogIn class expose the logged in user via a method or property, rather than "reaching into" the main menu to update it.

Comment: (As an aside, C# classes are not generally referred to as "scripts". There *is* a facility for using C# as a scripting language, and Unity also refers to code as "scripts" quite often, but neither of these is the context here.)

Comment: You are creating a loop. The first instance of LogIn creates an instance of MainMenu and this instance creates an instance of LogIn and this instance creates an instance of MainMenu and so on until you are out of memory.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.